# iphone .png image not showing up in device

Tags: iphone, xcode, png

ok, i set some .png files image as uimage in my table cell. they show up nicely when i run them using iphone simulator. when i run them in my device, they up not show up. what seems to be the problem?

i only "error" i got is unable to debug when i install my app to my device, which shouldn't be a problem as i never set for debug.

does anyone knows why?

thks in advance!

code:

```
- (void)setIcon:(UIImage *)newIcon
{
    [super setIcon:newIcon];
    iconView.image = newIcon;
}
```

where iconview.image is from nib. newIcon is loaded in from plist, 1.png etc.

Comment: I think you'll need to show some code.

Comment: i name my image file as 1.png, 2.png etc.
which part of my code are you refering to? as it loads well in simulator..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is the uppercase/lowercase letter usage of your file names exactly consistent between the source code or plist strings and the actual file names in your app's bundle?  Case awareness is a difference between the Mac OS and iOS file systems.

Comment: hi, i am using numbers. 1.png etc

Comment: ha, its the .png and .PNG! didn't know extentsion will cause a problem! thks a million!

Comment: I had the same problem, and i had JPG and jpg. I couldn't figure it out. Thanks SO MUCH